# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Future' in Jupyter Notebook online

Tags: python, input, jupyter-notebook, arguments, typeerror

When I try to run the following code in Jupyter notebook online:

```
   age=int(input('enter your age'))
   print(age)
```

I get TypeError:

```
  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

  Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()

  1 age=int(input('enter your age'))

  2 print(age)

   TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Future'
```

But the same code works normally in Jupyter notebook offline. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me what is causing this error.

Comment: I suspect that somewhere else in your code the built-in function *input* has been overridden with a reference to a class called *Future* - possibly concurrent.futures.Future

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly other classes named Future in the scope of what you're doing but this emulation of your problem may help you to figure out what's wrong:

```
from concurrent.futures import Future

input = Future

int(input())
```

Which generates the following exception:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Future'
```

Are you perhaps using the name 'input' as a variable name elsewhere in your code?

Comment: No, I opened a new notebook and the only code that I have in it is the one that I posted in the question, I don't have any other variables so unfortunately this is not solution to my problem.